# Almond pound cakes erupting

Tags: cake

In the last two weeks I have made 5 almond pound cakes with varying levels of failure. The biggest problem I'm having is that 3 out of 5 of the cakes have over flowed. The 3 that over flowed used no baking powder or baking soda. Each time I made them I put less and less batter in the pan. I'm so frustrated, I'm ready to give up. What am I doing wrong?

The only variation I made to the recipe was a little extra almond extract.

If you have access to fresh eggs--they make it amazing.  The key is mixing it very well!

```
3 Cups Sugar
2 Sticks of Butter
1/2 Cup Crisco
6 Eggs
1 Cup Milk
3 Cups Plain Flour
1 tsp Vanilla
2 Tsp Almond Flavoring
```

Mix: 3 cups sugar, 2 sticks of butter (at room temp), 1/2 cup White Crisco (not the butter-flavored type)  Mix until very creamy.

Add eggs in one at a time, mixing well after each one.

Add half the milk and half the flour. Mix well. Add the rest of the flour and milk. Mix well.

Add the flavorings and mix well.

Cook in a Bundt Pan- I spray it well with Baker's Joy so it won't stick.
Bake at 325ºF for 1 hour 15 minutes to 1 hr 30 minutes or until a toothpick comes out clean.

Let rest out of the oven for 15 minutes and then remove from pan.

Answer (score 3):

The recipe looks fine. I suspect that you are incorporating too much air into the batter when you are mixing. Try:

1. Mixing less - shorter time/slower speed and/or use a regular beater rather than a whisk
2. pouring the batter then giving the tin a good hard tap down on the bench - this will make large bubbles rise to the top and come out of the batter.

Comment: if it's large air bubbles that are the problem, there will often be 'tunneling' (strange worm-like holes going through the cake), and it's a sign that it's over mixed (gluten development makes the cake too strong, and holds the air bubbles from escaping)